# Rails, named scope not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I defined an simple named scope for my patient model, as you can see here:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :treatments
scope :recent_treatments, order('dateg desc')
```

So and in my view:

```
<% @patient.recent_treatments.each do |treatment| %>
  <tr class="<%= category_table_row_class(treatment.category) %>">....
  <td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %><span id="anzahl"><%= tr.....
```

But somehow its not working, i get the error:

```
 undefined method `recent_treatments' for #<Patient:0x39a92f0>
```

So i have no clue what i made wrong, besides this it would be nice if somebody could explain me why named scopes are not best practice in rails and what i should use instead?

Comment: Is `dateg` an attribute of Patient?

Comment: your `@patient` variable is a Patient instance, the scope you need should be in the Treatment model ;)

Comment: @mbratch No, i copied it from another question i saw on stackoverflow

Comment: That would be the problem. And it looks like @MrYoshiji and Mr. Hallstrom just indicated the answer.

Comment: can somebody explain me why named scopes dont have a good reputation?

Comment: Who says they have a bad reputation?

Comment: Named scopes could be overused perhaps in some cases to do complex things that might be better suited using another method perhaps, but certainly the example you have here seems a reasonable usage. I haven't heard of any particular issues.

Comment: http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/ @muistooshort

Comment: That's an old article based upon one person's opinion because of that person's bad experience. If you read his final update (from 2011), it says: *...I feel I should clarify that the bug that triggered this issue has been fixed quite a while ago. I’ve since mostly used scopes for “simple” rules and class methods for more complex rules because in my opinion it reads better. Mainly, whether you use scopes or class methods has, again, become a matter of personal taste. My recommendation is to choose your own style or agree on one style with your fellow developers.*

Comment: @mbratch: It is even worse than that, the blog's author really should learn a little more about Rails and keep himself up to date: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments). Class methods *are* scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have your scope on the wrong model.  If I understand correctly, for a given patient you'd like a list of their treatments, most recent first.  In that case you want something like this:

```
class Patient < AR::Base
  has_many :treatments
end

class Treatment < AR::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  scope :recent, order('dateg desc')
end

@patient.treatments.recent.each do....
```

Comment: that works! Thank you! But one more thing, why are named scopes not good practice or what should i use instead?

Comment: @EmSta Named scopes are great practice.  You should definitely be using them.  And I am in my code example above.